# Online photo management for non-profit organization

Tags: web, photo-management, sharing, tagging

I'm looking for photo hosting for a nonprofit I work with, and it looks like most sites are tailored towards individual or professional photographers, not for groups of people.

We run a summer program, with a handful of staff and new participants every summer.  We'd like to enable participants to upload, caption, and tag photos.  Staff should be able to admin the system.

What we really need is:

- private access for members only, via private URL or password.
- admins create folders, manage photos, and set up a password for members to be able to upload.
- participants should be able to upload, tag, and caption their own photos.
- admins can download full-res originals

Features which would be nice:

- Different admins for different folders
- Comments and likes
- Facebook integration for login

We are willing to pay for this.

I looked at flickr, but the photostream setup doesn't really give us the organization we want.  I looked at smugmug, but it doesn't look like their system lets guest uploaders tag and caption photos.  It also requires a paid account or social networking account to comment, which will work for most but not all of our users.  I know there are plenty of other photo hosting sites, but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so I don't need to try each of them one by one to see if it will work for us.

Comment: Have you checked out facebook groups? you can create a closed group that is only visible to people who you accept into it

Comment: I think most free social media websites do that for you, but if you want it to be exactly match your requirements then you have to pay for web design agency to create a website from your requirements

Answer (score 1):

[PhotoShelter](http://photoshelter.com) might be one of your options. You can also write a connector to your web-site, so your web-galleries or collections can be accessible directly on your web-site.

Answer (score 1):

Check out a new service called Snapphound at www.snapphound.com.  It has all of these admin features and more, plus allows you to further market and fundraise around your cause, among many other features.

Comment: As you are new here (Welcome, by the way), please know that it needed to show your affiliation with a promoted service, if that should be the case.